# Choose data frames by dynamic names

Tags: r, loops, left-join

I have several frames called y2010, y2011, y2012, ... and a frame called z.
"firstcolumn" contains fitting names.
I want to match the content of each frame (y2010, y2011, y2012, ...) by left_join to z within a loop.

```
for(i in 2010:2017) {
z<-left_join(z, paste0("y", 2011) , by="firstcolumn")
}
```

But I cannot choose the frames y2010, y2011, y2012, ... by paste0.
How can I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `get`:

```
z <- left_join(z, get(paste0("y", 2011)), by="firstcolumn")
```

Answer (score 1):

To avoid a for-loop, you can use `mget` to put them in a list and `lapply` to `merge`,

```
library(dplyr)

lapply(mget(ls(pattern = 'y[0-9]+')), function(i) left_join(z, i, by = 'firstcolumn'))
```

Comment: Yup. I thought that OP wanted that. I wasn't sure (was between `Reduce` and `lapply`) but I thought that they wanted a separate df for each merge (or at least that's how I translated the for-loop)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you might also want to look at `Reduce`:

```
Reduce(function(x, y) left_join(x, y, by = "firstcolumn"), 
       mget(c("z", paste0("y", 2010:2017))))
```

---

It's always better to provide some sample data along with expected output. Here's some sample data:

```
ls() ## Just to show I'm starting with nothing in my workspace
# character(0)
set.seed(1)
list2env(setNames(replicate(9, data.frame(firstcolumn = sample(letters[1:5], 3), data = sample(10, 3, TRUE), stringsAsFactors = FALSE), FALSE), c("z", paste0("y", 2010:2017))), .GlobalEnv)
ls()
# [1] "y2010" "y2011" "y2012" "y2013" "y2014" "y2015" "y2016" "y2017" "z"
```

Here's a comparison of using `Reduce` with using your `for` loop:

```
library(dplyr)
Reduce(function(x, y) left_join(x, y, by = "firstcolumn"), 
       mget(c("z", paste0("y", 2010:2017))))
#   firstcolumn data.x data.y data.x.x data.y.y data.x.x.x data.y.y.y data.x.x.x.x
# 1           b     10      2        8        3          4          7           NA
# 2           e      3      1       NA       NA          9          9           NA
# 3           d      9     NA        5        7         NA         NA            5
#   data.y.y.y.y data
# 1            5    3
# 2           NA   NA
# 3            8    9

usingGet <- function() {
  for(i in 2010:2017) {
    z <- left_join(z, get(paste0("y", i)) , by="firstcolumn")
  }
  z
}
#   firstcolumn data.x data.y data.x.x data.y.y data.x.x.x data.y.y.y data.x.x.x.x
# 1           b     10      2        8        3          4          7           NA
# 2           e      3      1       NA       NA          9          9           NA
# 3           d      9     NA        5        7         NA         NA            5
#   data.y.y.y.y data
# 1            5    3
# 2           NA   NA
# 3            8    9
```

Comment: I ll undelete then and wait for their respond (just in case)